# Inequality with projection in convex set

Tags: convex-analysis, projection

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a closed and convex set.
Due to the non-expansive of projection as 
$$\|\text{Proj}_{\mathcal{X}}(x) - \text{Proj}_{\mathcal{X}}(y)\| \leq \|x-y\|,$$
where $\text{Proj}$ is the projection operator.

My question is that given $u, v \in \mathcal{X}$ and a constant $\alpha \in (0,1)$, for any $x, y$, will the following inequality hold?
$$ \|(\alpha\text{Proj}_{\mathcal{X}}(x) + (1-\alpha)u) - (\alpha\text{Proj}_{\mathcal{X}}(y) + (1-\alpha)v\| \leq \|(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)u)-(\alpha y + (1-\alpha)v)\|.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily. In $\Bbb{R}^2$, take
\begin{align*}
x &= (2, 2) \\
y &= (1, -1) \\
u &= (-2, -2) \\
v &= (-1, 1) \\
\alpha &= \frac{1}{2} \\
\mathcal{X} &= \operatorname{conv}\{u, v\}.
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Proj}_\mathcal{X}(x) &= v \\
\operatorname{Proj}_\mathcal{X}(y) &= \left(-\frac{7}{5}, -\frac{1}{5}\right),
\end{align*}
and
$$\|(\alpha\operatorname{Proj}_\mathcal{X}(x) + (1 - \alpha)u) - (\alpha \operatorname{Proj}_\mathcal{X}(y) + (1 - \alpha)v)\| = \frac{3\sqrt{10}}{10},$$
(I think; it's definitely positive!) but
$$\|(\alpha x + (1 - \alpha)u) - (\alpha y + (1 - \alpha)v)\| = 0.$$

Comment: Thank you for replying. However, you may ignore the condition $u, v \in \mathcal{X}$.

Comment: @ruobot OK, I think I've fixed it. I'll be honest, I'm not being super careful with my calculations. The point is, it's possible for the convex combinations between $x$ and $u$, and $y$ and $v$, to agree, but the corresponding combinations to not agree once you've projected $x$ and $y$.